# Scroll validation on HTML5 canvas elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

This is a follow up from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323956/limit-scroll-ability-on-html5-canvas-elements) I asked a few weeks ago.

I've got two lines of scrolling boxes where there is now validation in place to prevent scrolling past the first box, but I'm having difficulty working out how to do something similar in the opposite direction to prevent scrolling past the last box.

This is the code that handles the scroll event from one row:

```
first = Object.keys(boxes)[0];
lScroll += e.deltaY;

if (lScroll < 0) {
    canlScroll = true;
} else {
    canlScroll = false;
    lScroll = 0;
}

Object.keys(boxes).forEach(function(key) {
    if(canlScroll && boxes[key]['s'] == 'l') {
        boxes[key]['y'] += e.deltaY;
    }
});

if (!canlScroll && lScroll == 0) {
    if (boxes[first]['y'] < 10) {
        var delta = 10 - boxes[first]['y'];

        Object.keys(boxes).forEach(function(key){
            if(boxes[key]['s'] == 'l') {
                boxes[key]['y'] += delta;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Full example working here: https://jsfiddle.net/hbd6nL4e/1/

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution to your problem: 
RE-EDITED:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  c.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrolling, false);

  c.ctx = ctx;
  c.c = c;

  draw(ctx, c);
});

function draw(ctx, c) {
    // clear canvas for redraw
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    // draw shapes
    Object.keys(boxes).forEach(function (key) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#999";
        ctx.fillRect(boxes[key].x, boxes[key].y, boxes[key].w, boxes[key].h);
    });
}

function scrolling(e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;

  // scroll left boxes
    if (mouseX <= 400) {
        first = Object.keys(boxes)[0];
        lScroll += e.deltaY;
    //console.log(lScroll);  
    //console.log((Object.keys(boxes).length/2)*(-100));
        if (lScroll < 0 && (lScroll>=(Object.keys(boxes).length/2)*(-100))) {

            canlScroll = true;
        } else {if (lScroll<(Object.keys(boxes).length/2)*(-100)){
            lScroll = (Object.keys(boxes).length/2)*(-100);
            canlScroll = false;//console.log("final down:"+lScroll);
        }

          else  {lScroll = 0; canlScroll = false;//console.log("final up:"+lScroll);
                }
        }

        Object.keys(boxes).forEach(function(key) {
                if(canlScroll && boxes[key].s === 'l') {
                  //console.log(e.deltaY/1.65);
                    boxes[key].y += Math.round(e.deltaY/1.65);
                }
            }
        );

        if (!canlScroll && lScroll === 0) {
            if (boxes[first].y < 10) {
                var delta = 10 - boxes[first].y;

                Object.keys(boxes).forEach(function(key){
                    if(boxes[key].s === 'l') {
                        boxes[key].y += Math.round(delta);
                      //console.log(""+Math.round(delta));
                    }
                });
            }
        }

  // scroll right boxes
    } else {
        first = Object.keys(boxes)[12];
        rScroll += e.deltaY;

        if (rScroll < 0 && (rScroll>=(Object.keys(boxes).length/2)*(-100))) {

            canrScroll = true;
        } else {if (rScroll<(Object.keys(boxes).length/2)*(-100)){
            rScroll = (Object.keys(boxes).length/2)*(-100);
            canrScroll = false;//console.log("final down:"+rScroll);
        }

          else  {rScroll = 0; canrScroll = false;//console.log("final up:"+rScroll);
                }
        }

        Object.keys(boxes).forEach(function(key) {
                if(canrScroll && boxes[key].s == 'r') {
                    boxes[key].y += (e.deltaY/1.65);
                }
            }
        );

        if (!canrScroll && rScroll === 0) {
            if (boxes[first].y < 10) {
                var delta = 10 - boxes[first].y;
                Object.keys(boxes).forEach(function(key){
                    if(boxes[key].s == 'r') {
                        boxes[key].y += delta;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }

    draw(e.target.ctx, e.target.c);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Edited and now it is working with both mouse and pointer pad. The reason why it was not functioning is because mouse and pointer pad deltaY are very different: one is 100px steps the other 2.5px. Now the only issue is that firefox is not handling it, in fact it works just on Chrome.

Check it here: http://output.jsbin.com/gobaguhehe

Comment: This seems to allow you to scroll further than I want. I'd like it to stop when the last box is at the bottom of the screen. I assume this could be done by adding the height of the canvas to the if, but it also seems to jump back to the top when it reaches the bottom?

Comment: You just have to modify the second condition of the first if: if (lScroll < 0 && (lScroll>=(Object.keys(boxes).length/2)*(-100))) to something that could work for you. E.g. if your boxes number are always 12, just change it to (-800) that means that you need to calculate how many box you want displayed on the screen and do the math.

Comment: Alternatively you can use (Object.keys(boxes).length/2*100) - Math.abs(lScroll) to calculate the number of boxes displayed and stop the scrolling if the number is lower than that. The choices are plenty

Comment: if I do: if (lScroll < 0 && (lScroll>=(Object.keys(boxes).length/2)*(-120)+800)) {


I get an infinite scrolling effect - doing 120 to account for the margin between the boxes and 800 as the height of the canvas.


Not sure what to do about making it stop at that point rather than it jumping back up

Comment: Check the new solution, by editing the ratio of which the page is scrolling, by 60px rather than 100px, it stops your element from scrolling further. I edited to suits the previous solution provided but as I mentioned there are many ways to do it.

Comment: I'm still seeing an infinite scrolling effect where it jumps back up to the top when trying to scroll past the last element. Is this not the case for what you are seeing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114955/discussion-between-marco-valente-and-lobodemon).

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet - Hoping to dedicate a bit more time to it this week though